# External script included via document.write can not update global variables?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, document.write

I just did some tests to find out if it is possible to change global variables from external scripts included via document.write. I did expect that is is possible - **but it is not**! Does some one has an explanation on this?

Findings:

Updates to global variables by:

- external scripts included via document.write will **not** become visible to the including script
- inline scripts included via document.write become visible to the including script

First the original script tag is finished - then the scripts added via document.write are executed in the order of insertion.

Content written via document.write using results from javascript execution on the other hand is inserted in the correct order (deepth-first) - but nethertheless uses the value defined at the scripts execution time.

Adding an alert(x) at the end of the external file causes the modified value to be propagated back to one and base context. But it seems to be impossible to trigger this without user interaction.

**Test Setup**

My test is the following: from an inline script in base.html i use document.write to include a javascript one.js which itself includes file two.js. Each file prints the value via console and via document.write and sets the value.

Snippet of inline script from **base.html**

```
var x = "base";
console.log("x at start base: "+x);
document.write("<p>x at start base "+x+"</p>")
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"one.js\"></scri'+'pt>');

document.write("<p>x at end base: "+x+"</p>");
console.log("x at end base: "+x);
```

File **one.js**

```js
console.log("Start One: "+x);
document.write("<p>Start One "+x+"</p>");

x = "1";
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"two.js\"></scri'+'pt>');

document.write("<p>End One "+x+"</p>");
console.log("End One: "+x);
```

File ***two.js***

```js
console.log("x at start two.js: "+x);
document.write("x at start two.js: "+x);

x = "2";

document.write("<p>x at end two.js: "+x+"</p>");
console.log("x at end two.js: "+x);
```

**Results**

Console output:

```
x at start base: base
x at end base: base

x at start one.js: base
x at end one.js: 1

x at start two.js: 1
x at end two.js: 2
```

Page output: Show the correct order but with wrong values (2 set in file two.js is not propageted to end of one.js and end of base js.

```
x at start base: base
x at start one.js: base
x at start two.js: 1

x at end two.js: 2
x at end one.js: 1
x at end base: base
```

Thanks in Advance
Cotopax

Comment: Why are you inserting scripts via `document.write`? Why is this important to you?

Comment: Might be a bit late - but context for this is to overwrite document.write for late loading of advertising placements. We started using bezen framework (http://bezen.org/javascript/demo/dynamic-script-loading-with-bezen-load.html) for this. This framework works good for stuff you have under control. But we identified the limitation above - which seems to be a hard blocker for a 100% solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - controlling the insertion point for document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536970/javascript-controlling-the-insertion-point-for-document-write)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwriting iframe's document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256147/overwriting-iframes-document-write)